# On the existence of smooth surfaces with a given Picard rank

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $d \geq 5$, then there exists  $ V \subset \mathbb P^N =|\mathbb O_{\mathbb P^3}(d)|$, which is a countable union of subvarieties, such that for all $S \in \mathbb P^N - V$,  the restriction map $\text{Pic}(\mathbb P^3) \to  \text{Pic}(S)$ is an isomorphism, i.e $ \text{Pic}(S) \cong \text{Pic}(\mathbb P^3) \cong \mathbb Z$ (This is by  Noether-Lefschetz theorem). This guarantees the existence of smooth surfaces of degree $d$ in $\mathbb P^3$ with picard number $1$.

Now my questions are the following: Let $d \geq 5$ be arbitrarily fixed.

$(i)$ Can we say that for every $n \geq 2$, there exists a smooth hypersurface $S$ of degree $d$ in $ \mathbb P^3$ such that $\text{Pic}(S)$ is generated by $n$ elements ?

$(ii)$ $(a)$To be more precise Is this at least true for $n =2$?

$(b)$ If it's true for $n=2$, then does there exist a necessary and sufficient condition in the literature to check when a line bundle is ample?

Can anyone give me any reference?

Any help from anyone is welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use dimension count to see whether the following can be achieved. Take $n$ disjoint lines and find a smooth surface of degree $d$ containing them (this is where you need to do your dimension count). If $d\geq 5$, then the the canonical bundle is ample and then by intersection theory, these $n$ lines are linearly independent in the Picard group.

For $n=2$ and $d\geq 5$, the dimension count is easy, but for large $n$, you may also need large $d$, if you use this method.

For the last part, I am not sure what type of conditions are you looking for checking ampleness. Of course, more or less by definition, one necessary and sufficient condition for $L$ on a smooth projective surface to be ample is $L^2>0, L\cdot C>0$ for all curves $C$. I suspect you are not looking for this, but am not sure what you are looking for.

On a lighter note, $U$ almost always remind one of open sets, and your $U$ is more or less closed, since it is the union of countably many closed sets. I would have used $U$ for its complement.

Comment: I should have written $V$ or $K$ instead of $U$. We know that by dimension count a general surface of degree $d \geq 5$ does not contain any line. On the other hand, is the dimension count that you mentioned given by: $h^0(\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^3}(d))$ - no of independent conditions imposed by the union of two skew lines $l_1 \cup l_2$ in$\mathbb P^3$? But In that case,  we  are counting all such hypersurfaces, not especially smooth. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @HARRY Yes,  general hypersurfaces of degree large do not contain lines. So, you look at the ones containing, say a fixed two skew lines. Among those, find one which is smooth. There is always one, the Fermat, for appropriate lines.